# Tarantool fiber behavior with fiber.yield() and fiber.testcancel()

Tags: lua, tarantool, fibers

I ran into an unexpected behavior while building Tarantool app based on fibers.

Simple reproducer of my code looks like this:

```lua
local log = require('log')
local fiber = require('fiber')

box.cfg{}

local func = function()
    for i = 1, 100000 do
        if pcall(fiber.testcancel) ~= true then
            return 1
        end

        fiber.yield()
    end

    return 0
end

local wrapfunc = function()
    local ok, resp = pcall(func)
    log.info(ok)
    log.info(resp)
end

for _ = 1, 100 do
    local myfiber = fiber.create(wrapfunc)
    fiber.sleep(0.02)
    fiber.kill(myfiber)
end
```

and it prints to log `false, fiber is cancelled`. Moreover, if I use the following `func`:

```
local func = function()
    for i = 1, 100000 do
        if pcall(fiber.testcancel) ~= true then
            return 1
        end

        pcall(fiber.yield)
    end

    return 0
end
```

it prints to log `true, 1`, and if I use

```
local func = function()
    for i = 1, 100000 do
        if pcall(fiber.testcancel) ~= true then
            return 1
        end

        if pcall(fiber.yield) ~= true then
            return 2
        end
    end

    return 0
end
```

it prints to log `true, 2`.

I expected that after yielding from running `myfiber`, if control returns to the external fiber and it calls `fiber.kill(myfiber)`, the next time control returns to the cancelled `myfiber` we will be in the end of cycle iteration and on the next iteration code will successfully return 1. However, the work of `func` ends with throwing error `fiber is cancelled`, not with return. So how the real life cycle of yielding fiber works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no unexpected behaviour here. I believe it mostly documentation issue. Let me explain. I've simplified your example a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tarantool

local fiber = require('fiber')

local f1 = function() fiber.yield() end
local f2 = function() pcall(fiber.yield) end

local func = function(fn)
    fn()
    if not pcall(fiber.testcancel) then
        return 'fiber.testcancel() failed'
    end
end

local fiber1 = fiber.create(function() print(pcall(func, f1)) end)
fiber.kill(fiber1)
local fiber2 = fiber.create(function() print(pcall(func, f2)) end)
fiber.kill(fiber2)
```

The output would be:

```
false   fiber is cancelled
true    fiber.testcancel() failed
```

When you call `fiber.kill`, `fiber.yield()` or `fiber.sleep()` just raises an error, so your fiber is not able to reach `fiber.testcancel` and just dies. When you do `pcall(fiber.yield)`, you basically suppress this error and proceed. Then `fiber.testcancel` checks its fiber status and reraise an exception. But this is a silly example.

Now, with bigger chunks of code, when lots of function invocations involved, you usually want to catch those errors during `yield`, do some finalisation work and call `fiber.testcancel()` to promote error upwards (imagine multiple checks of this kind in different parts of big stacktrace). I believe it is the basic use case, `fiber.testcancel` was introduced for, besides discussions if its design is usable or not.

P.s. And yes, occasional exceptions of such yield calls are not documented. At least I could not find anything in the [fiber](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.4/reference/reference_lua/fiber/) page